# Push Notification with Image - iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, push-notification

Hi I just want to show push Notification with Image. Im using the below code and im not sure where im doing mistake it took me more than 3 weeks, I gone through many Links but still it couldn't be fixed. the below is my App delegate code

**AppDelegate.Swift**

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

var deviceTokenString:String = ""
var badgeCount = 0

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Push Notification

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
    {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in

            // actions based on whether notifications were authorised or not

            guard error == nil else {

                //Display Error.. Handle Error.. etc..

                return
            }

            if granted
            {

                //Do stuff here..

            }

            else {

                //Handle user denying permissions..

            }

        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }




    registerForRemoteNotification()


    // iOS 10 support
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        // iOS 9 support
    else if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        // iOS 8 support
    else if #available(iOS 8, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        // iOS 7 support
    else {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.sound, .alert])
    }

    return true
}

func registerForRemoteNotification() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

             //   UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

      //  UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5
    }
}

func incrementBadgeNumberBy(badgeNumberIncrement: Int)
{
    let currentBadgeNumber = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber
    let updatedBadgeNumber = currentBadgeNumber + badgeNumberIncrement
    if (updatedBadgeNumber > 0)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = updatedBadgeNumber
    }
    else
    {
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Couldn't register: \(error)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    deviceTokenString = deviceToken.hexString()

    //  deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    print("device token: \(deviceTokenString)")


}

// Push notification received
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    // Print notification payload data

    badgeCount = badgeCount + 1
    self.incrementBadgeNumberBy(badgeNumberIncrement: badgeCount)

    print("Push notification received: \(data)")

}

//  Notification will present call back
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])


    print("UserInfo: \(notification.request.content.userInfo)")

    var userinfo = NSDictionary()
    userinfo = notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary

    let imgData = userinfo.value(forKey: "data")! as! NSDictionary

    let url = imgData.value(forKey: "attachment-url")

    let imgUrl = URL(string: url as! String)!

    //  1. Create Notification Content
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()


    //  2. Create Notification Attachment

    URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: imgUrl)
    {(location, response, error) in

        print("location: \(location!)")

        if error == nil
        {
            if let location = location
            {
                // Move temporary file to remove .tmp extension

                let tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()

                let tmpFile = "file://".appending(tmpDirectory).appending(imgUrl.lastPathComponent)

                print("tmpFile: \(tmpFile)")

                let tmpUrl = URL(string: tmpFile)!

                print("tmpUrl: \(tmpUrl)")

                try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: tmpUrl)

                // Add the attachment to the notification content

                if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "attachment", url: tmpUrl) {

                    content.attachments = [attachment]

                    print("attachment: \(content.attachments)")

                    //  3. Create Notification Request

                    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: String.UNNotificationRequest.NormalLocalPush.rawValue,

                                                             content: content, trigger: nil)

                    content.title = "\(userinfo.value(forKeyPath: "aps.alert.title")!)"
                    content.body = "\(userinfo.value(forKeyPath: "aps.alert.body")!)"
                    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
                    content.badge = (UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1) as NSNumber;
                    content.categoryIdentifier = String.UNNotificationCategory.Normal.rawValue

                    //  4. Add to NotificationCenter

                    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

                    center.add(request)
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error: \(error!)")
        }
        }.resume()
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
//  Notification interaction response call back
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("\(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")

    var userinfo = NSDictionary()
    userinfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary

    let imgData = userinfo.value(forKey: "data")! as! NSDictionary

    let url = imgData.value(forKey: "attachment-url")

    let imgUrl = URL(string: url as! String)!

    //  1. Create Notification Content
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "\(userinfo.value(forKeyPath: "aps.alert.title")!)"
    content.body = "\(userinfo.value(forKeyPath: "aps.alert.body")!)"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = (UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1) as NSNumber;
    content.categoryIdentifier = String.UNNotificationCategory.Normal.rawValue   //  设置通知类型标示

    //  2. Create Notification Attachment

    URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: imgUrl) { (location, response, error) in

        if let location = location {

            // Move temporary file to remove .tmp extension

            let tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()

            let tmpFile = "file://".appending(tmpDirectory).appending(imgUrl.lastPathComponent)

            let tmpUrl = URL(string: tmpFile)!

            try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: tmpUrl)



            // Add the attachment to the notification content

            if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: tmpUrl) {

                content.attachments = [attachment]
            }
        }

        // Serve the notification content

        // self.contentHandler!(content)

        }.resume()

    //        if let attachement = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "attachment", url: imgUrl, options: nil)
    //        {
    //            content.attachments = [attachement]
    //        }

    //  3. Create Notification Request
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: String.UNNotificationRequest.NormalLocalPush.rawValue,
                                             content: content, trigger: nil)

    //  4. Add to NotificationCenter
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request)

    let responseNotificationRequestIdentifier = response.notification.request.identifier

    if responseNotificationRequestIdentifier == String.UNNotificationRequest.NormalLocalPush.rawValue ||
        responseNotificationRequestIdentifier == String.UNNotificationRequest.LocalPushWithTrigger.rawValue ||
        responseNotificationRequestIdentifier == String.UNNotificationRequest.LocalPushWithCustomUI1.rawValue ||
        responseNotificationRequestIdentifier == String.UNNotificationRequest.LocalPushWithCustomUI2.rawValue {

        let actionIdentifier = response.actionIdentifier
        switch actionIdentifier {
        case String.UNNotificationAction.Accept.rawValue:

            break
        case String.UNNotificationAction.Reject.rawValue:

            break
        case String.UNNotificationAction.Input.rawValue:

            break
        case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:

            break
        case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:

            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    completionHandler();
}


}

extension Data
{
func hexString() -> String
{
    return self.reduce("") { string, byte in
        string + String(format: "%02X", byte)
    }
}
}
```

And below is my Extension Code which im using for custom Push notification,

**Extension.swift**

```
import Foundation

extension String {

enum UNNotificationAction : String {
    case Accept
    case Reject
    case Input
}

enum UNNotificationCategory : String {
    case Normal
    case Cheer
    case CheerText
}

enum UNNotificationRequest : String {
    case NormalLocalPush
    case LocalPushWithTrigger
    case LocalPushWithCustomUI1
    case LocalPushWithCustomUI2
}
}

extension URL {

enum ResourceType : String {
    case Local
    case Local1
    case Remote
    case AttachmentRemote
}

static func resource(type :ResourceType) -> URL
{
    switch type {
    case .Local:
        return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cheer", withExtension: "png")!
    case .Local1:
        return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "hahaha", withExtension: "gif")!
    case .Remote:
        return URL(string: "http://ww1.sinaimg.cn/large/65312d9agw1f59leskkcij20cs0csmym.jpg")!
    case .AttachmentRemote:
        return URL(string: "https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-mark.png")!
    }
    }
}

extension URLSession {

class func downloadImage(atURL url: URL, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        completionHandler(data, error as NSError?)
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
}
```

and My Api response is,

```
[AnyHashable("aps"):
 {
alert =     {
    body = test;
    title = "N-Gal";
};
"mutable-content" = 1;
sound = default;
}, 
AnyHashable("data"): 
{
"attachment-url" = "https://www.n-gal.com/image/cache/catalog/HomeBanner/Banners/1172X450-N-Gal-Footwear-Banner-100x100.jpg";
}]
```

This code is based on the tutorial https://github.com/maquannene/UserNotifications. Please give me a solution to fix this... Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Can you tell where it's failing? Does it receive the push notification from APNS? Can you create a local notification _without_ an image? Does the image get downloaded?

Comment: Im not getting any error, and im receiving push notification, but there is no image and also the image is getting downloaded and the file path is something like, file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/552F6491-A95C-463E-8924-FD8BD53A629D/tmp/NG0330-(1)-100x100.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your code snippet I conclude you are talking about **remote** notifications. That's an important distinction. If you want to 'enrich' a remote notification (e.g. add an image), you need a `UNNotificationServiceExtension`:

> For local notifications, the app adds attachments when creating the
>   rest of the notification’s content. **To add attachments to a remote
>   notification, use a notification service extension to modify the
>   notification content before it is delivered**. For more information
>   about implementing a notification service extension, see 
>   [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)

Source: [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationattachment). (emphasis mine)

That extension lives outside of your app and is called *before* the user gets to see the remote notification. That way you have the chance to load all of your remote resources before the notification is scheduled for delivery. For more info on the lifecycle of extensions and how they communicate with their host app, take a look at the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html).

To add the extension in Xcode, go to `File > New > Target` and select a *Notification Service Extension*:

[image: New target pane]

This will create new extension target and embed it in the host target:

[image: New extension target]

In the `NotificationService.swift` file you will find the entry point where you can start customising the notification content.

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Modify the notification content here...
            bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"

            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}
```

Be sure to take look at the [UNNotificationServiceExtension class overview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) for more details.

Comment: Thanks..... I already created a service extension but a small key mistake i was doing. Anyway thanks for your answer.. Upvoted! for a neat answer...

Comment: i am using this but i have receive notification in app-delegate class. How to redirect NotificationService class method.